# Extraer parte de Información Consulta MYSQL

Tags: mysql

tengo en mi base de datos una tabla llamada semestre que tiene solo el campo ID y el campo NOMBRE SEMESTRE. Si hago una consulta al semestre actual obtengo "1 semestre - 2021", lo que necesito es extraer solo el año de esa consulta.

TABLA SEMESTRES
ID (INT 11)
NOMBRE_SEMESTRE (VARCHAR 50)

SELECT * FROM `semestres` WHERE id= $id_formulario_1;

RESULTADO = 1 SEMESTRE - 2021

Comment: Buenas, por favor agrega estructura de la BD y el codigo de la consulta

Comment: Hola, actualice la pregunta

Comment: Bueno, para mejorar la pregunta, sigue consejos de [ask]. Por otro lado, solo tienes 1 columna con datos, ¿Por que solo una? y por que una tabla solo para eso ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función [substring_index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index), obteniendo el último elemento y con el separador -, puedes aplicar la función [trim](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) para quitar espacios en blanco detrás y delante.

```
SELECT
  TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(semestres, '-', -1)) as sem
FROM
  semestres
WHERE 
  id = 1;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono..